# AJAX security concern, preventing people from performing actions on behalf of another user via links

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, csrf

Let's say a user wants to delete a post and you want to perform this asynchronously, you'd probably do something like...

```
$.post('https://mysite.com/execs/remove.php?&post_id=' + post);
```

Or you wouldn't, because you don't want someone to be able to just copy that link with the user's post id and trick them into deleting it. So instead I do this...

```
$.post('https://mysite.com/remove.php?post_id=' + post + '&visit_session=' + visit_session);
```

I plugin their secret visit session id which is called via ajax earlier in the script and changes every time they login. So unless a user can guess their random id the link will fail and the user will be safe...

Then I wondered what's stopping someone from creating a webpage to steal this user's visit session id? Couldn't a malicious person essentially just copy and paste my ajax request in their own site and do something like this...

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://mysite.com/visit_session.php',
  dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
    window.location = "https://mysite.com/remove.php?post_id=POSTID&visit_session=' + data.visit_session";
}
});
```

So if a user set up a site with that little script in it, and then linked it to the user they wanted to trick into deleting their post, wouldn't it do just that? (Assuming the user is currently logged into my site).

Assuming I'm right in my thinking here, what can I do to prevent this from happening?

EDIT: Instead of polling the visit session variable inside my javascript file I know I could just do something like...

```
<script>
visit_session = "<?php echo $_SESSION['visit'] ?>";
</script>
<script src="https://mysite.com/javascript/main.js"></script>
```

This would prevent a malicious user from polling it on behalf of another user. However I'd rather avoid having to add that to every page and just keep it all in the main.js file if possible. So if anyone has any suggestions or tips I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) forbids the access to the response of cross-origin requests unless the server explicitly allows it according to [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

So this piece of code run at a different origin won’t be able to read `data` unless the server explicitly allows the different origin to do so. The latter would be the case if the server responds with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` which allows any origin to share the response.

Comment: Guess I spent all that time worrying for nothing, thank you very much.

Comment: @Gumbo: What about starting Chrome with the web security flag disabled? (on MAC OSX terminal: $ open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir) This should let you bypass this AJAX cross-domain security policy no? Is it right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, the first requires using a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) (ideally with a HTTPS cookie) to associate a user with a login.  It's the best knows technique in PHP so finding documentation on how to do it shouldn't be hard.  However, because it relies on client state it's not RESTful.

If you do need it to be RESTful, then the other option is to use [HTTP digest authentication](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).  This doesn't require any particular client state so it's REST compliant, but it does require the client to send the correct digest with every request.

Comment: You do not require a login to use sessions in PHP.

Comment: Actually yeah, you're right.  Put it down to a case of the evenings.  :)  But you would require a login if the goal is to ensure that the request is coming from the user it claims to come from.

Comment: @MikeBrant Well the language in the OP is indicative of an existing login system, in which case the user would have to be logged in before making the ajax request in order to verify it's actually their post

Comment: Yes as orourkek said, I have a login system which saves many user variables in sessions. The security issue is on the end of performing actions with AJAX requests, not with PHP. If you look at the last snippet of code I put in there, it would grab the visit session id and then redirect the user back to my site. So it would pass the PHP session variable authentication, because it is that user.

Comment: @GordonM Ian clearly describes a scenario of [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_\(CSRF\)). And for CSRF, it doesn’t matter whether the victim is logged in or not, although an authenticated user poses quite a better victim as he has some privileges an attacker might want to exploit. And unless a logged in user has to re-authenticate for every action he want’s to perform, any action triggered by an attacking site will be seen by the server as any other action that was triggered by the victim itself as it’s the same browser that sends it.